# How can I impl IntoIterator for a newtype vec without calling collect()?

Tags: rust

Here's a tiny sample program I made:

```rust
type Index = usize;
type ValType = u32;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct NewVec(pub Vec<ValType>);

impl IntoIterator for NewVec {
    type Item = (Index, ValType);
    type IntoIter = <Vec<(Index, ValType)> as IntoIterator>::IntoIter;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.0
            .into_iter()
            .enumerate()
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
            .into_iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![100];
    let new_v = NewVec(v.clone());
    
    println!("Vec::into_iter:    {:?}", v.into_iter());
    println!("NewVec::into_iter: {:?}", new_v.into_iter());
    
}
```

This program runs correctly, and generates this output:

```
Vec::into_iter:    IntoIter([100])
NewVec::into_iter: IntoIter([(0, 100)])
```

However NewVec::into_iterator calls collect() in order to create a new Vec, and then call it's into_iter().

My goal is to eliminate the call to collect() and just return an iterator directly. I wish to avoid unnecessary allocation.

Is this possible?

Note that if we remove the call to .collect() we get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
11 |       fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
   |                             -------------- expected `std::vec::IntoIter<(usize, u32)>` because of return type
12 | /         self.0
13 | |             .into_iter()
14 | |             .enumerate()
15 | |             .into_iter()
   | |________________________^ expected `IntoIter<(usize, u32)>`, found `Enumerate<IntoIter<u32>>`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::vec::IntoIter<(usize, u32)>`
              found struct `Enumerate<std::vec::IntoIter<u32>>`
```

But I don't know how to transform an `Enumerate` into a `std::vec::IntoIter`, or if that's even possible.

See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1f9e5af2b4fff1f81fdeabd3a53e3e82)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are couple ways you can accomplish this. I'll try to show as many as I know of and explain their pros and cons, so that you could choose the one that fits your use case best. In all of my examples I made `IndexVec` generic over `Vec`'s elements.

#### Solution 1: Directly name iterator type in the `IntoIter` associated type

This is pretty straight-forward. Since all you do is calling `into_iter` in a `Vec` and then wrapping it in an enumeration, you can just name this type directly.

```rust
use std::iter::Enumerate;
use std::vec::IntoIter as StdVecIntoIter;

pub struct IndexVec<T>(pub Vec<T>);

impl<T> IntoIterator for IndexVec<T> {
    type Item = (usize, T);
    type IntoIter = Enumerate<StdVecIntoIter<T>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.0.into_iter().enumerate()
    }
}
```

**pros:**

- very easy solution that works on stable rust
- very little boilerplate code

**cons:**

- non-encapsulation friendly (If you would like to change underlying implementation you would have to change `IntoIter` type, which would be breaking change)
- Iterator types can get *very* complicated, and some are unnameable (for example [Filter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Filter.html) with passed closure)

#### Solution 2: Use custom wrapper type

We can create a custom wrapper type for the iterator the same way as we created it for `Vec`. This allows encapsulation of the implementation, but results in large amounts of boilerplate. This is just a draft of full implementation, because for production code you would like to implement also [FusedIterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FusedIterator.html), [ExactSizeIterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html) and [DoubleEndedIterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html) for `IndexVecIter`.

If you would also want to iterate over borrowed `IndexVec` you would have to create two more wrappers, which would triple the amount of boilerplate.

```rust
use std::iter::Enumerate;
use std::vec::IntoIter as StdVecIntoIter;

pub struct IndexVec<T>(pub Vec<T>);

impl<T> IntoIterator for IndexVec<T> {
    type Item = (usize, T);
    type IntoIter = IndexVecIter<T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        IndexVecIter(self.0.into_iter().enumerate())
    }
}

pub struct IndexVecIter<T>(Enumerate<StdVecIntoIter<T>>);

impl<T> Iterator for IndexVecIter<T> {
    type Item = (usize, T);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.0.next()
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        self.0.size_hint()
    }
}
```

**pros:**

- allows you to encapsulate your implementation (you can change it later without introducing braking change)

**cons:**

- very large boilerplate
- as with the previous solution you can have problem with exactly naming iterator types

#### Solution 3: Dynamic dispatch

To avoid the need to exactly name the iterator type we can use *dynamic dispatch*. This will result with an allocation and pointer indirection, but there are many scenarios where this costs are not problematic.

```rust
pub struct IndexVec<T>(pub Vec<T>);

impl<T> IntoIterator for IndexVec<T>
where
    T: 'static,
{
    type Item = (usize, T);
    type IntoIter = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Self::Item>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Box::new(self.0.into_iter().enumerate())
    }
}
```

**pros:**

- very easy solution that works on stable rust
- very little boilerplate
- partial encapsulation (you can change inner iterator, but `Box<dyn Iterator>` is part of the interface)

**cons:**

- additional runtime cost of heap allocation and dynamic dispatch
- works only for `T: 'static`

#### Solution 4: `impl Trait`

Using currently (`rustc 1.73.0`) unsable feature `impl_trait_in_assoc_type` you can specify that associated type `IntoIter` is `impl Iterator`. This works similarly to `impl Trait` in return position. The compiler will infer concrete type during compilation and will be able to perform all of it's optimizations, but to the caller this type is *hidden* and the only thing the caller can do with it is to use the interface of the trait. Since this is exactly what `IntoIter` provides anyway, this is a perfect fit!

Although this feature is not stable yet, it is [very close to stabilization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063) and will *probably* be stabilized for the `Rust 2024 edition`.

```rust
#![feature(impl_trait_in_assoc_type)]

pub struct IndexVec<T>(pub Vec<T>);

impl<T> IntoIterator for IndexVec<T> {
    type Item = (usize, T);
    type IntoIter = impl Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.0.into_iter().enumerate()
    }
}
```

**pros:**

- very easy solution
- very little boilerplate
- full encapsulation
- ability to use unnameable types in the underlying implementations

**cons:**

- is not stable yet

Comment: Solution 3 (dyn dispatch) doesn't require static `T`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=624975e1d392ca971f25432ab6b4110a It's not clear, though, whether it can be done without introducing the lifetime to `IndexVec`. (The impl-trait-in-assoc-type version clearly allows it.)

Comment: thanks.  This is an amazingly detailed and helpful answer.  I'm sure it will help many others besides myself.   For now I went with solution 3.   Solution 4 looks perfect, so I really hope it makes it into rust 2024!

Answer (score 10):

Since `.enumerate()` provides an iterator, I would simply return it directly.
We just have to adapt `Self::IntoIter` in order to match the exact type (the error messages of the compiler help us a lot).

```rust
impl IntoIterator for NewVec {
    type Item = (Index, ValType);
    type IntoIter = std::iter::Enumerate<std::vec::IntoIter<ValType>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.0.into_iter().enumerate()
    }
}
```

---

Here is the suggestion from the comments, with boxing + dynamic dispatch.

```rust
impl IntoIterator for NewVec {
    type Item = (Index, ValType);
    type IntoIter = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Self::Item>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Box::new(self.0.into_iter().enumerate())
    }
}

...

for e in new_v.into_iter() {
    println!("{:?}", e);
}
```

Comment: In real world programs sometimes the type is impossible to spell, because eg. it uses lambda functions. Then you can do `type IntoIter = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = (Index, ValType)>>;` and box the return value. It is still technically an allocation, but that is a single small object, not the big collected values of the container.

Comment: @rodrigo: Sadly, that does mean it's not `Debug`, so the OP can't print the iterator directly, but [their code still works if the thing showing the debug output explicitly collects it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6f3b174714b0a07d263b02a4bad2684a), and in real code, they could just iterate it and avoid the temporary container. (To be clear, not criticizing your suggestion, it's a decent idea even if the type is possible to spell, to avoid tight coupling on the type and just avoid spelling really complex types, just mentioning the change it needs).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes, lacking the `Debug` is a minor inconvenience, and you can't write `dyn Iterator + Debug` yet.

Comment: And naturally one day you will be able to use an `impl trait` in a trait return type, such as in this nightly [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4dec354fcfc75a5856e930bd11a0ce8b). That will be awesome!